# Choosing design patterns for basic classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am new to design patterns and have read a substanitial information (probably to much) and think I may be trying to over pattern a solution.

I have two concepts to model:

Customer - The types of customers are defined and quite fixed (Company, Personel, Sole Trader...). Various functionality will arise depending on the type of customer.

Users - The users are generally classified as either internal/external and if internal the role they perform is a hierachy and privileges will be allocated on the role.

I was going to use the decorator class and then implement a business entity objects for the processing rules is that inline with best practices or am I over complicating it and  standalone class and sub class with the business logic would be OK?

Comment: The Decorator pattern carries a complexity and performance handicap; but when it is needed there is often no other answer to the problem. If you are asking the question, I expect this is not one of those times.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was over complicating it

Comment: If some level of your class diagram suddenly starts to explode with classes that all differ from each other in very small ways, Decorator may be the solution.